# How to apply a style to a ListBox in code

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a case where some people are divided into several groups with the people and groups coming from a database.  I want to display this data as a series of ListBoxes for each group with the people in that group displayed in the ListBox.  I do this in code for each group as follows:

1. First I define a ListBox

   ```
   lbx = New ListBox
   With lbx
      .ContextMenu = cm
      .DisplayMemberPath = "FullName"
      .SelectedValuePath = "PersonID"
   End With
   ```
2. Then I populate an ObservableCollection (of Person) from the database then assign that collection as the ItemsSource of the ListBox.

   ```
   lbx.ItemsSource = ocGrouMembers
   ```
3. Then I add the ListBox to a panel named "pnl" that I've defined in XAML.

   ```
   pnl.Children.Add(lbx)
   ```

Now comes the problem: I want to change the presentation of some of the people in the ListBoxes.  First, I thought I'd define a Style in XAML with TargetType = ListBoxItem.  But this won't work because nowhere in code do I ever explicitly define the ListBoxItems so there is no way to define a style for them.

Second, I thought of creating a DataTemplate in XAML but as far as I can tell there is no way in code to apply a DataTemple directly to the ListBoxes.

I hope this is clear.  How can I change the appearance of the names in theListBoxes in this case?

**EDIT: Final Solution**

I ended up defining data template in XAML as follows:

```
<DataTemplate
    DataType="ListBoxItem"
    x:Key="dtpListBoxItem">
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="txtPerson"
        Text="{Binding FullName}">
    </TextBlock>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=Chair}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="txtPerson"  Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter TargetName="txtPerson" Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

And in code used it as follows:

```
lbx = New ListBox
    With lbx
        ... other properties ....
        .ItemTemplate = DirectCast(Resources("dtpListBoxItem"), DataTemplate)
    End With
```

Comment: With an appropriate view model you could do all this in XAML. Your view model would have a collection of groups, each with a collection of people. You would bind it to an ItemsControl with a ListBox in its ItemTemplate.

Comment: I have a collection of groups, each with a collection of people and, as indicated in my OP, I have the bindings already working.  Your comment merely reiterates the part that I've already done.  Rather, the question is how to modify the presentation of the data.

Comment: Creating a ListBox in code behind doesn't actually look like a reasonable approach. Anyway, take a look at the ListBox's ItemTemplateSelector or ItemContainerStyleSelector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, **using MVVM is good practice** , but please find some workaround.

You can use data template , and check data based on that you can style :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Group}">
        <DataTrigger.Value>
            <src:Group>Group1</src:Group>
        </DataTrigger.Value>
      <DataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DodgerBlue" TargetName="border" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" TargetName="descriptionTitle" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" TargetName="currentPriceTitle" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" TargetName="border" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" TargetName="border" />
      </DataTrigger.Setters>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Group}">
        <DataTrigger.Value>
            <src:Group>Group2</src:Group>
        </DataTrigger.Value>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" TargetName="border" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" TargetName="descriptionTitle" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" TargetName="currentPriceTitle" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="star" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" TargetName="border" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" TargetName="border" />
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Some Links :

[datatemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.triggers(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Data-Binding-Demo-](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-Demo-82a17c83/)

[datatemplates-and-datatriggers-in-wpf](http://putridparrot.com/blog/datatemplates-and-datatriggers-in-wpf/)

Apply data-template dynamically :

```
 ListBox dynamictemplatelistBox = new ListBox();
        //dynamictemplatelistBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; /// we cant set template and displaymember at same time.
        dynamictemplatelistBox.ItemsSource = list;

        string xamlTemplate = "<DataTemplate DataType=\"{x:Type ListBoxItem}\">"
                                + "<TextBlock x:Name=\"txt1\" Text=\"{Binding Name}\" />"
                                 + "<DataTemplate.Triggers>"
                                    + "<DataTrigger Binding=\"{Binding Path=Name}\" Value=\"test\">"
                                        + "<Setter TargetName=\"txt1\" Property=\"Background\" Value=\"Yellow\" />"
                                    + "</DataTrigger>"
                                 + "</DataTemplate.Triggers>"
                                 + "</DataTemplate>";
        var xaml = xamlTemplate; // String.Format(xamlTemplate, "ListBoxItem");
        var context = new ParserContext();
        context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]);
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        var template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
        //dynamictemplatelistBox.Template = template;
        dynamictemplatelistBox.ItemTemplate = template;

        parentStackPanel.Children.Add(dynamictemplatelistBox);
```

or you can define style in XAMl and set dynamically from code:

```
dynamictemplatelistBox.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["testCodeBehindtemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

Comment: MVVM is NOT always good practice - even reasonable advocates acknowledge that.  In my case, it is not.  A data template, no matter how well formed, is not a solution to my problem, as I documented in the OP.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer but see my OP edit for the final solution.